# Unorthodox function invocation in javascript (jshint.W067)

Tags: javascript, split

I am working on javascript with jshint esversion 11. I have a function to get the language of the application. I have this code to get it but jshint is throwing an error.

Code

```
let localeToReturn = navigator?.language?.split("-")[0].toUpperCase()
```

> The JSHint is giving an issue in-between "split" and "(".

> navigator?.language value is like "en-us".

[image: Exact warning]

I am not sure what it is.

Let me know if more details are needed

Comment: Please may you provide the exact error? Or at least a [mcve] showing the linting error?

Comment: "Unorthodox function invocation" is the exact warning I am getting.

Comment: This apparently [was a bug](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/3551) and has been [fixed in version 2.13.1](https://jshint.com/blog/2021-08-10/release-2-13-1/)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am using "/* jshint esversion: 11 */"  what should i do then, so i should not get the warning ?

Comment: What version of jshint are you using? You might need to update it

Comment: I'm getting the same with this code, also set to esversion:11
`someDomElement?.previousElementSibling?.querySelector('.cssClassName')?.id`

Comment: @CWDSubs don’t worry about the ecmascript version. Try updating jest itself?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't use jest, but updating to the latest JSHint version bundled in PhpStorm did the trick

Comment: @CWDSubs sorry, I meant jshint, not jest.